# Mysqli database connection does not works normally

Tags: php, mysqli

See the following code in PHP.

```
$db = new mysqli($CONF['host'], $CONF['user'], $CONF['pass'], $CONF['name']);
    if ($db->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error;    
    }
$db->set_charset("utf8");
$db->autocommit(FALSE);
$db->begin_transaction();
$result= $db->query("update users set is_verified=1 where id=10 and is_verified=0"); //$result is allways true
$affRow = $db->affected_rows; //allways returns -1 
//die();
$db->commit();
```

**Problems:**

1. $affRow is allways equal to -1 even when a row affects in database.
2. If I uncomment the `die()` code, query affects the database while `$db->commit()` not executed yet.
3. `$db->affected_rows` is 1 just before reading the value. Just before reading, it changes to -1 and $affRow becomes -1 too!! Why these are happening? Where am I wrong?

Comment: Did you try reading `$db->error`?  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: you tried change order like get affRows after commit?

Comment: @Devon : Yes. It is empty and without any errors!

Comment: try after commit  $db->affected_rows;

Comment: @daremachine : I have tried that. after commit, `$db->affected_rows` changes to 0 and after reading that value, It becomes -1 again !!!!

Comment: I have debuged the code line by line. I don't know why these are happening? I have changed my machin too. You can try that for yourself and see.

Comment: execute the query in phpmyadmin if you have and see if it returns an error

Comment: @vSugumar : Executes successfully in phpmyadmin. Without error